# Grammatical function of "all" within "All about economics."

Tags: pronouns

Does *all* within:

> **All** about economics.

play the role of pronoun?

Comment: Please give the full sentence.

Comment: I've actually made it up, but there are many book titles that are worded in this same fashion (All About Electronics, All About Gardening,...).

Comment: I believe it's an elliptical version of "it's all about economics"; in which case, "all" functions as a quantificational adjunct in the clause structure.

Comment: But in the sentence "**everything** about economics", *everything* is a pronoun, and [Webster's ](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all) lists *everything* as a synonym of *all* under the pronoun section.

Comment: "Everything" is a not a pronoun, but compound determinative (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002). See also [Why dictionaries are bad when it comes to parts of speech](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635)

Comment: @Norbert MW is the worst dictionary available. It is years behind current thinking. "All" is undoubtedly a determinative in examples like yours, see here [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/all). And "everything" is a compound determinative, not a pronoun see here [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/everything).

Comment: @BillJ is the Oxford Dictionary a more reliable source? because it also defines *everything* as a pronoun.

Comment: Not much! The one I gave you link to is generally more up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It's all about economics*

No, "all" is not a pronoun here, but a determinative. The entirety meaning doesn't apply to "about economics" but to "it". "All about economics" is not a PP (preposition phrase), not a single constituent. The "all" is an adjunct and the PP is just "about economics".

The meaning can be glossed as "It is entirely about economics".

(Note that I have inserted "it's" as subject+verb to enable the sentence to be analysed.)